Add bar spacing in x axis for multi-facet horizontal geom_bar (facet_share, facet_wrap)
I am trying to add spacing in my horizontal bar plot. I can do this with facet_share if I need to use only one facet group, but in this case I am faceting with two variables. I want to add space around the center of x axis, to be able to visualise the vertical text correctly (E, F, D, etc).
This is my code:
Q9 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B","A", "B")
Region <- c("Asia", "Europe", "America","Asia", "Europe", "America","Asia", "Europe")
Country <- c("D", "E", "F", "G", "D", "E", "F", "F")

d <- data.frame(Q9, Region, Country)

yn_try <- d %>%
  group_by(Q9, Region, Country) %>%
  summarise(perc = n()) %>%
  group_by(Country, Region) %>%
  mutate(n = perc, perc = perc/sum(perc)*100) %>%
  mutate(perc = case_when(Q9 == "A" ~ perc*-1, TRUE ~ perc)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Country, perc), y = perc, fill = Q9)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage (%)", title = "TITLE") +
  facet_wrap(~Region, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Country), y = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold.italic", size = 10),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), # Remove y-axis text
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) # Remove y-axis ticks

yn_try

This is what I am getting

Ideally I am expecting an output as if using facet_share, but this does not appear to work. The result should be the country group in the centre with space between the right and left bars to read clearly the text.

If I need a butterfly chart, and I can't use facets, I might do this:
library(ggplot2)

# make a simple butterfly chart by shifting x values and breaks by offset
# fake data

df <- data.frame(
  country = c("France", "Germany", "Italy"), 
  value = c(10, -6, 3)
)

offset = 2
p <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(
    aes(
    x = sign(value) * offset, 
    xend = sign(value) * (abs(value)+offset), 
    y = reorder(country, value), 
    yend = reorder(country, value),
    color = as.factor(sign(value))
    ),
    linewidth = 10)+
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = reorder(country, value), label = country), hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#ef6f00", "#2f8fff"))
# this is not yet working, the labels are not aligned with the bars
p

# define the breaks and labels
labels <- c(-10, -5, -0, 0, 5, 10)
breaks <- (abs(labels) + offset)* rep(c(-1, 1), each = length(labels)/2)
limits = range(breaks)

# add the offset to the x-axis
p +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = labels,
                     breaks = breaks,
                     limits = limits
                     )


Sorry Michiel, but that does not do quite what my point is. I am not having any continuous values in my data.

percentage is not continuous?
